# C + + cannot find the thread it created on ubuntu 18

Tags: c++

I write a simple c++ code. In my code, I create two threads, then I name the two threads **TCPCall30003Proc** and **TCPCall30004Proc**, but I can not find them using **top** command with option **-H**. My os is ubuntu 18.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>

void f1(int num)
{
    printf("1\n");
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void f2(int num)
{
    printf("2\n");
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::thread thd_1 = std::thread(f1, 1);
    std::thread thd_2 = std::thread(f2, 1);

    pthread_setname_np(thd_1.native_handle(), "TCPCall30003Proc");
    pthread_setname_np(thd_2.native_handle(), "TCPCall30004Proc");

    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think threads will show up in top, they run inside the same process don't they?

Comment: I agree with @JeffUK, but I think you can see the number of threads assigned to a given pid: `$ ps -o nlwp <pid>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the `pthread_setname_np` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html):

> The thread name is a meaningful C language string, whose length is restricted to 16 characters, **including the terminating null byte ('\0')**.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

You names are **17** characters, including the null-terminator.

If you check what `pthread_setname_np` returns it should return `-1` and with `errno` set to `ERANGE`.

You need to shorten your names.